# How to add delayed follower in Solr cloud for recovery form unexpected data delete

Tags: solr, database-replication, solrcloud

I am working on Solr cloud and today we faced one issue where someone accidentally removed all Indexes.
In master Slave set up we had delayed Slave to recover form these issues but i could not find anything in Could for same.
Could you please help me to add a delayed member in cloud to recover from unexpected conditions like this.

Thanks
Viren